# vb.net crystal reports distinct count

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

i have a sql database containing employees whose report will be generated by crystal reports.

Each employee's details Occupy a whole page. l have created an employees count such that it will display "Employee 1 of 10", then the second one will be "employee 2 of 10".

Both Summaries are supposed to reset on change of department.  my problem Is the 2nd summary that is supposed to count the total number of employees in that department works just like the 1st (eg. Employee 1 of 1, then the 2nd becomes '' employee 2 of 2").

In the first Summary, i used 'count ' while in the 2nd Summary i used 'distinctcount'. I need help making the summary work correctly, Any help Will be appreciated.

Comment: couldn't get your requirement may be your report design explanation could help to understand

Comment: When you say that you used `count` and `distinctcount` are you referring to the SQL you used for the query, or to Crystal Reports functions?